# Cannnot display data in PrimeNG tree component

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, primeng

my goal is to simply create a treeview using this https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tree component.

I currently have a small service with this method

TS:

```
 getMenuDetails(parentID: number) {
   let url = this.serverURL + 'api/Nodes/' + parentID;
   console.log(url);
   return this.http.get(url)
    .map(res =>  {
      return <TreeNode[]>res.json()
    })
 }
```

I'm calling this service in my component like this

TS:

```
export class TreeViewComponent implements OnInit {
  mainTree: number = 1;
  rootDetails: TreeNode[];

  constructor(private projectService: ProjectRoleService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.projectService.getMenuDetails(this.mainTree)
      .subscribe(res => this.rootDetails = res)
        console.log(this.rootDetails);    
      };
```

My problem is that I'm not able to display the data in

```
this.rootDetails
```

HTML:

```
<p-tree [value]="rootDetails"></p-tree>
```

Error:

**Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'Wurzel'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.**

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**EDIT 1:**

This is how my data returned from the service looks like

```
{
    descr: "WurzelNode"
    id: 1
    lvl: 1
    name: "Wurzel"
    parentid: 0
    position: 1
    rootid:1
}
```

Comment: How your data returned by your service look like ?

Comment: Hi there, I've added the data into the question now, hope it helps :)

Comment: Ok, so you're trying to assign an object to an array of `TreeNode` hence the error message.

Comment: Ohhh...thanks :D Do you know of another way to solve this?

Comment: Yes. Either you can make your service return data which corresponds to something like [that](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/primefaces/primeng/master/src/assets/showcase/data/files.json) either you transform your data which comes from the service in your component to have the same structure as an array of `TreeNode`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me a lot :D

Answer (score 2):

PrimeNg provides a templating functionality which allows you to use your custom json.

```
<p-tree [value]="files">
    <ng-template let-node  pTemplate="default">
        {{node.title}}
    </ng-template>
</p-tree>
```

In above code `title` is the json key, that I want to use to display in my tree.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case you were declaring your result as array,

```
    rootDetails: TreeNode[];
```

but what you fed into `[value]` is not an array according to your later explanations.
So switching to

```
    this.projectService.getMenuDetails(this.mainTree)
        .subscribe(res => this.rootDetails = [res]
```

instead will do the trick I assume.

Answer (score 0):

```
loadData(){
    this.loadDataService.getLazyFiles(
    this.URL,
    (response:any) => {
      this.config.nodes = response.map((elem) => <TreeNode>{

        label : `${elem.title}_MyValue`,
        data: elem.id,
        "expandedIcon": "fa fa-folder-open",
        "collapsedIcon": "fa fa-folder",
        leaf:false,
        type:"1",

      });

    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
 }
```

Apart from template as mentioned above, another approach as mentioned by @Antikhippe, was to map the response of the JSON data and create new object with the specified keys in .

P.S Including code, so that it helps someone looking for reference.